# What do you need Covariant Return Types for?

Tags: c#, language-features, return-type

In [this article](https://blog.ndepend.com/c-8-0-features-a-final-glimpse/), it is written that in C# 8.0 new feature of convariant return type will be included as the community asking for this feature for quite a long time.

Can anybody explain why and when this feature is required with practical example ?

Comment: see [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7538/31260)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly, it is worth noting that the article is very likely wrong. [There is currently a long list of features officially earmarked for C# 8.0](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+milestone%3A%228.0+candidate%22), but covariant return types is not one of them. That feature [is scheduled for X.0](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/49), ie it needs to appear in a major release, so *might* appear for 8.0 (but that's incredibly unlikely), more likely will be in 9.0 or 10.0 etc.

As for what use is the feature, [have a read of the original Roslyn issue from three years ago](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/357). It has numerous uses around being able to narrow the return type within methods in derived types, eg an implementation of a factory interface could specify that it returns a concrete type, rather than an interface.

For example, using generics, we can do something like:

```
public interface IFactory<T>
{
    T Create();
}

public class Foo{}

public class FooFactory : IFactory<Foo>
{
    public Foo Create() => null;
}
```

But if `IFactory` instead uses further interfaces for its abstractions, rather than generics, similar code isn't currently possible:

```
public interface IFoo {}

public interface IFactory
{
    IFoo Create();
}

public class Foo : IFoo {}

public class FooFactory : IFactory
{
    public Foo Create() => null; // Compiler complains at Foo; wants IFoo
}
```

Such code would become legal with covariant return types.

Answer (score 3):

Covariant return types means that an method override can specify a more specific return type than the base method. Eg.

```
class WebRequest {
    virtual WebRequest Create() { ... }
}

class HttpWebRequest : WebRequest {
    override HttpWebRequest Create() { ... }
}
```

Currently (without covariant return types) the overriden method have to specify the exact same return type, `WebRequest`, and you will have to manually cast the return value to `HttpWebRequest`, which is ugly.

Comment: As a workaround... wouldn't this already work if both classes implemented an interface with an `out T` generic argument? [gist](https://gist.github.com/he-dev/000253eb7f4a38a6c67436bc8570baa1)

Answer (score 3):

(Apologies beforehand, by C# is a bit rusty)

As mentioned in the other answers the big feature of convariant return types is that you can override virtual functions with functions that return a more specific return type.

For example:

```
public class Foo
{
    virtual public Foo getCopy(); { //Create a copy of this Foo and return it }
}
```

The `getCopy()` method returns a copy of the `Foo` it is invoked on, so far, so good. Let's add a class that inherits from `Foo`.

```
public class Bar : Foo
{
    override public Foo getCopy(); { //Create a copy of this Bar and return it as a Foo }
}
```

Note that without covariant return types we need to declare that we return a `Foo` (officially) instead of a `Bar` (even though we actually return a `Bar`). This might not be that bad until you write the following code.

```
//Copying things
Foo myFoo;
Foo myOtherFoo = myFoo.getCopy();

Bar myBar;
Bar myOtherBar = myBar.getCopy(); //Compiler error - getCopy() returns a Foo
```

Even though you know that myBar is a `Bar`, and that you (actually) get a `Bar` from the myBars's `getCopy()`, you need to cast the return value to get it to compile. Worse, it is a potential source for bugs...

```
public class Baz : Foo
{
    override public Foo getCopy(); { //Create a copy of this Baz and return it as a Foo }
}

//Copying more things
Foo myFoo;
Foo myOtherFoo = myFoo.getCopy();

Bar myBar;
Bar myOtherBar = myBar.getCopy() as Bar;

Baz myBaz;
Baz myOtherBaz = myBar.getCopy() as Baz; //Whoops
```

Notice the typo? Without covariant return values you might only notice during runtime (when the program crashes), with them the compiler can tell you at compile time: No, that can't work.

In summary: Covariant Return Values let you write shorter, preciser and safer code.